# What should be used to change the projection in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I wanted to create perspective projection in OpenGL and I created that manually by creating a camera position vector and a camera rotation matrix. After that, I wanted to see if there are anything that automatically does that in OpenGL. I have seen that there WAS glMatrixMode which was used for that purpose, but it seems like it is deprecated. I wanted to learn if there is a new way for creating any projection instead of manually creating the matrix or is this the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not any more. OpenGL got rid of the built-in matrix operations around the same time it moved to shaders. Now you're expected to write your own math code or bring your own math library.

I recommend using the library [glm](https://github.com/g-truc/glm). It includes, for example, versions of [gluPerspective](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/a00151.html#ga283629a5ac7fb9037795435daf22560f), [gluLookAt](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/a00151.html#gae2dca3785b6d5796e876114af58a60a1), [glTranslate](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/a00151.html#ga8925161ecc1767957900c5ca8b922dc4) as well as many other functions. All the math functions from old OpenGL are in here.

```
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
glm::mat4 myProjectionMatrix = glm::lookAt(
    glm::vec3(eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ),
    glm::vec3(centerX, centerY, centerZ),
    glm::vec3(0, 1, 0) // up vector
);
```

You can use [glm::value_ptr](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/a00158.html) to convert a `glm::mat4` matrix into a pointer you can give to OpenGL (e.g. to `glUniformMatrix4fv`).

---

`glMatrixMode` was not a math function; it just selected which matrix variable "slot" the matrix math functions would work on. OpenGL had a few different matrices. You used the same functions like `glTranslate` and they would edit the projection matrix, modelview matrix, colour matrix or texture matrix depending on which one you selected with `glMatrixMode`. This is now obsolete, because in modern OpenGL you have total control over how your shaders work. There aren't specific matrix slots any more - you can have whatever matrices you want, as shader variables.